# Updating TableView within containerview

Tags: ios, swift3

I have my `UIViewController`, which is a person's profile page, it displays their name and picture. Within that `UIViewController` I have a `UIContainerView` that displays a static `UITableView`. I'm having a little trouble updating the cells of the table when the profile page loads. Here's my storyboard:

[image]

I have tried the following, within my `UIViewController`.

I created an outlet to my `UIView` and passed the person object to it.

In my `UIView` I called the segue to pass the object to the `UITableViewController` and from there I was going to update some labels.

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == "containerSegue"{
        let statsTable = segue.destination as! CollectionTableViewController
        statsTable.currentPerson = currentPerson
    }
}
```

My Segue is never called though. I have moved it to the main `UIViewController` in case it should be called from there, but again not called. What am I doing wrong with this approach?

Comment: and add statsTable.tableView.reloadData() also.

Comment: @DeepakKumar, the segue is never called for the value to be passed though?

Comment: Check my answer at bottom. Segue method will never be called because tableviewcontroller is being added as childviewcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have set the Segue Identifier to "containerSegue" you *should* get it in your "Stats" view controller.

Are you using Swift 3? It's possible you just have the func definition wrong:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "containerSegue" {
        let statsTable = segue.destination as! CollectionTableViewController
        statsTable.currentPerson = currentPerson
    }
}
```

That *should* work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Swift3, and the segue should be in my UIView, as opposed to my UIViewController?

Comment: It should be in the ViewController class... In the image you posted, I'm assuming the View Controller labeled "Stats" is of class "StatsViewController.swift" (or something similar).