# How to reload tableView inside of a containerView?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I have the following setup: BaseVC (container view inside)-connectedTo-commentsVC (inside of here is a tableView which will be filled with custom commentCells).

Upon the baseVC loading this gets called:

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let VC = segue.destination as? CommentsVC {

        VC.selectedMedia = selectedPost?.media[numberMedia]
        VC.commentCellDelegate = self
        VC.parentView = commentsContainer
        commentsVC1 = VC
        VC.post = selectedPost!
    }

}
```

Then when a button is pressed in the BaseVC this gets called, bringing up the commentsVC with the tableView and then fetching the data that should go within it:

```
@objc func CommentsTapped(_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //Bring up the comments view and load all data into it.
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        print(self.commentsVC1.commentCellDelegate!)
        self.commentsVC1.commentCellDelegate!.updateCommentSheet(frame: self.initalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 180))
        self.loadComments()
        //I tried calling self.commentsVC1.tableView.reloadData() here but nothing happens
    })
}
```

Then at the bottom of the BaseVC class I have an extension which holds all the methods for the tableView:

```
extension Phase3VC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if arrayOfComments.count == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return arrayOfComments.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = commentTableViewCell()
    do {
        print("jdkhfjkfhasjklfhds")
        let url = URL(string: (arrayOfComments[indexPath.row].user.profileImageUrlString)!)
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

        cell.dateOfComment.text = arrayOfComments[indexPath.row].date
        cell.commentText.text = arrayOfComments[indexPath.row].commentText
        cell.profImage.image = image
        cell.username.text = arrayOfComments[indexPath.row].user.username
    } catch {


          print(error, ": Failed in do block converting image")
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

So my question is **how do I reload the tableView in order to get the data into the tableView?** I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604585/reload-tableview-inside-a-uiview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414625/updating-tableview-within-containerview) but neither helped.

**I have attempted:**

```
func loadComments(completion: @escaping(()->())) {
```

and called at the end of firebase func like: `completion()` (do be aware it is .childAdded)

and then do:

```
self.loadComments {
                self.commentsVC1.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

But it did not work

### **Update:**

Here is the fetching function:

```
    func loadComments(completion: @escaping(()->())) {
    print("Fetch comments")

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.arrayOfComments.removeAll()
    ref.child("Comments").child(selectedPost!.user.userID!).child(selectedPost!.media[0].postID!).child("\(numberImage+1)").observe(.childAdded) { (snap) in
        let commentID = snap.key
        let uid = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "UID").value as! String
        ref.child("users2").child(uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value
            let profileImage = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImage").value

            let newUser = User(theuserID: uid, theUsername: username as! String, theprofImage: profileImage as! String)

            let commentText = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Comment").value!
            let timeStamp = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "timeStamp").value!
            print(timeStamp, "This is the timeStamp")
            let date = ConvertDate(mediaTimestamp: timeStamp as! Double, isItForP3: false).getDate!

            let newComment = Comments(newUser: newUser, text: commentText as! String, timeStamp: date, NcommentID: commentID)
            self.arrayOfComments.append(newComment)
            print(self.arrayOfComments.count, ": comments added")
            self.commentsVC1.tableView.reloadData()

            completion()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadComments` is asynchouous so

```
self.loadComments {
     self.commentsVC1.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

so `reloadData` is called before fetching the comments

---

```
// it would be like this 
func loadComments(completion:@escaping(()-())) { 
   Api.getcomments { 
        // alter the dataSource array of the table
        // either reload the table here or do the below line 
        completions()
   }
 }
```

Comment: So I did:     func loadComments(completion: @escaping(()->())) {
and called at the end of firebase func like: completion() (do be aware it is .childAdded) and then do:             self.loadComments {
                self.commentsVC1.tableView.reloadData()
            }
But it did not work

Comment: you have to make sure that you update the data source array of the table before the reload

Comment: Sorry, what is a data source array?

Comment: I call the completion() method at the end of each "loop" so when the first reload happens there should be at leased one comment init.

Comment: Are sure that the array isn't empty inside the callback when you write `completion` , also make sure you set delegate & dataSource of the table

Comment: So inorder to set the datasource and delegate I would have to do that in the commentsVC so I moved that and the extension to that side. The problem then is how do I access the values inside the array. moving the fetching over would not work as I need to fetch only when a button is pressed in the BaseVC. So not sure if there is another way or if this even is teh best or correct way